# NSDate compare always returns NSOrderedAscending

Tags: objective-c, nsdate

I am checking if a given date & time is already past the current date & time. Here's what I've done

```
NSString *End = [[values objectAtIndex:index]valueForKey:@"EndTime"];

fmt.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss";
    utc = [fmt dateFromString:End];
    NSDate *endDateInLocalTimezone = [utc dateByAddingTimeInterval:timeZoneSeconds];
    fmt.dateFormat = @"MMMM dd, hh:mm a";
    endDateInLocalTimezone = [fmt stringFromDate:endDateInLocalTimezone];

    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    now = [fmt stringFromDate:now];


    if([endDateInLocalTimezone compare:now] == NSOrderedAscending)
    {
        index++;
        continue;
    }
```

I got a **July 03, 5:29 PM** *endDateInLocalTimezone* and comparing it to my *now* which is **June 30, 12:18 PM**. It still say's that is in NSOrderedAscending, which means the left operand is smaller than the right operand. But in the given case, the right operand is smaller than the left operand. Why is it still getting inside the if?

Comment: FYI, the first `dateFormat` should use `yyyy`, not `YYYY`.

Comment: My bad, updated it now. What is the problem in my compare now?

Comment: also, unrelated, I'm not sure what your intent of the adjusting of the date by the interval of the time zone. That suggests some misunderstanding of how date objects work, though there's not enough here to diagnose what your intent was. But if you ever find yourself adjusting a date object by your time zone, there is generally some deeper problem there.

Comment: Cause the date needs to be adjusted depending on the user's time zone

Comment: Yeah, so tell the `NSDateFormatter` what timezone the string was originally created, and it will convert it. The problem is that you don't likely know whether daylight savings was in place at that point or not, so manually adjusting dates is just asking for trouble. `NSDateFormatter` takes care of all of that for you. See answer below.

Comment: By the way, if `EndTime` is using a 24 hour time format, you should also use `HH`, not `hh`. And if this is from a web service, you probably want to set `locale`, too, as per [Apple Technical Q&A #1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1480/_index.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing string renditions of the date objects, rather than the date objects, themselves.  Compare dates, not strings.

---

For example:

```
NSString *dateString = values[index][@"EndTime"];

formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
formatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];           // the EndTime is in GMT/UTC, tell you formatter that
formatter.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]; // you generally should make sure to use `en_US_POSIX` in case user is not using gregorian calendar
NSDate *date = [fmt dateFromString:dateString];

NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

if ([date compare:now] == NSOrderedAscending) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Should I change my second dateFormat or is it in this lineendDateInLocalTimezone = [fmt stringFromDate:endDateInLocalTimezone]; the stringFromDate

Comment: @drbj - You should compare `utc` to `[NSDate date]` directly, and _lose_ those two `stringFromDate` calls.